# My router somehow started blocking Gmail Chat

Tags: networking, router, gmail

I have a home router running OpenWRT. I just went from having my Mac Mini wireless-ly connected, to plugging it in directly to the route via ethernet.

Now my gmail chat has stopped working. I'm not sure why. I can visit other websites.

I decided to try bypassing the router and plugged the Mac Mini right into the modem and gmailc chat worked.

Any ideas? I'm getting the "Unable to reach Gmail. Please check your Internet connection or company's network settings" error.